# Usage guidance of the "excerpt" of the wiki tag

Tags: soporte, etiquetas

When editing a wiki tag they ask for a body and a usage guidance.

What is this usage guidance?

**Nota:** Quizás explicándolo en castellano entienda a qué se refiere este campo de texto que la gente es obligada de rellenar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's so you can direct people that will use the tag. So they can know in which cases they can use that tag.

For example you have the tag `vocabulario` that is used for the meaning of words or how a specific word may be used. It is not to be confused with `selección-de-palabras` that is used for the words used as a group in a specific context, or if they are well used together with others.

Comment: So the *body* is to explain what the tag is, and *usage guidance* to when to use it?

Comment: Yep! That's about right. :)